# Is it possible to disable (or reject) selection of parent terms in taxonomy reference fields at node creation or edit?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

for instance, for a particular Vocab. and User Role..

Is it possible to achieve that in code? That parent terms will be rendered only as labels and not checkboxes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) allows you to disable the selection of parents. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I have installed Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget but I have not found a setting that restricts selection of parent terms.